# What should go in an ssh key comment?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, comments

I noticed when I list my identities with `ssh-id -l` that I can't differentiate them because they were all created by me on this PC, so the comments take the form of `user@mypc` which is not particularly helpful in telling them apart. What is best practice to put in the ssh key comment field?